# Pushing Updates to Devices Running Node App

Tags: node.js, updates, auto-update

I am creating a NodeJS app that runs as a server on the Raspberry Pi micro controller.  I intend to sell the product and would like to be able to push updates to this server code at will.

Clearly, this is not a standard deployment so I'd like to know if there are any other ways to solve this problem.  Given that the server should usually have an internet connection, I can imagine it working one of these ways:

- Separate server code from the logic.  Allow user to click on web page to curl a file with the new logic which is downloaded from my distribution server and subsequently replaces the previous file.  Restart server after replace.  Might involve a Git repo and checking out latest commit.
- Separate process runs a check against a Docker hub repo.  If an update is available, it lets the main process know.  When the user triggers an update, the first process pulls down the new image and restarts the process.

Any thoughts about how I should best implement this update functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Check out resin.io.  It is a docker based raspberry pi push service.  You just check your code into the git repository they provide and they push it out to all your devices.  Just include a Dockerfile in the base directory of your checkin.